# Make row inside an overflowed div expand 100% of that overflowed div

Tags: html, css

I am having issue making my row to be 100% width. Here is my setup

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
}
  div {
    min-width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the row only gets its width from the parent container, and doesn't expand all the way (the background color gets cut off). Why is it not going full width?

Comment: inline-flex instead of flex and min-width instead of width

Comment: after using inline-flex you will get issue with whitespace at the bottom that you can fix by adding `vertical-align: top;`